# How can I restructure the data where it would group the same IDs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this data where it repeats the items that were placed. How can I group the data according to their id and add an array of variations that will store the various colors and their quantity?

This is the current sample data that I have:

```
 const data = [
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Green",
        quantity: 2
      },
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Pink",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Black",
        quantity: 11
      },
      {
        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",
        name: "Notebook",
        price: 250,
        size: "200",
        cat: "CM",
        color: "Red",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",
        name: "Notebook",
        price: 250,
        size: "200",
        cat: "CM",
        color: "Green",
        quantity: 4
      }
    ];
```

I just want to know how I could destructure this data to something like this where the duplicated id will be group and then the color and quantity will be pushed inside the variations array:

```
   id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
    name: "Tumbler",
    price: 200,
    size: "500",
    cat: "ML",
    variations: [
       {name: "Green", quantity: 1},
       {name: "Black", quantity: 10},
    ]
```

From what I have done, I have merged it already except for the part for the variations array. How can I create the `variations` array ?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/data-restructure-u2ss8z?file=/src/App.js

```
const mapById = data.reduce(
  (acc, { id, name, size, cat, price, color, quantity }) => {
    acc[id] = {
      id,
      name,
      size,
      cat,
      price,
      color,
      quantity
    };
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
```

Comment: That is very good progress. What now needs to be done is, if an `id` already exists in `acc`, then the `name` & `quantity` need to be pushed into a new prop named `variations`. Will post an answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially you have to check if an object with `id` key is present, if not create it with an empty `variations` array. then added to the variations array based on the current `id`

```js
const data = [      {        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",        name: "Tumbler",        price: 200,        size: "500",        cat: "ML",        color: "Green",        quantity: 2      },      {        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",        name: "Tumbler",        price: 200,        size: "500",        cat: "ML",        color: "Pink",        quantity: 1      },      {        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",        name: "Tumbler",        price: 200,        size: "500",        cat: "ML",        color: "Black",        quantity: 11      },      {        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",        name: "Notebook",        price: 250,        size: "200",        cat: "CM",        color: "Red",        quantity: 1      },      {        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",        name: "Notebook",        price: 250,        size: "200",        cat: "CM",        color: "Green",        quantity: 4      }    ];
    
const mapById = data.reduce(
  (acc, { id, name, size, cat, price, color, quantity }) => {
    acc[id] ??= {id,name,size,cat,price,variations:[]}
    acc[id].variations.push({name:color, quantity})
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(mapById)
```

Answer (score 1):

Presented below code-snippet may be helpful to achieve the objective. Please note that this returns an `Array` and not a map. However, if one removes the `Object.values` wrapper, then the result will be a map/object with `id` being the key.

```js
const regroupArray = arr => (
  Object.values(
    arr.reduce(
      (acc, {id, color, quantity, ...rest}) => (
        id in acc
        ? {
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
              ...acc[id],
              variations: acc[id].variations.concat([{
                color, quantity
              }])
            }
          }
        : {
            ...acc,
            [id]: {
              id,
              ...rest,
              variations: [{
                color,
                quantity
              }]
            }
          }
      ),
      {}
    )
  )
);

const data = [
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Green",
        quantity: 2
      },
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Pink",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "aRLMZkiSU7T0lcsPCSsV",
        name: "Tumbler",
        price: 200,
        size: "500",
        cat: "ML",
        color: "Black",
        quantity: 11
      },
      {
        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",
        name: "Notebook",
        price: 250,
        size: "200",
        cat: "CM",
        color: "Red",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: "y9ECyZBKp2OBekmWym4M",
        name: "Notebook",
        price: 250,
        size: "200",
        cat: "CM",
        color: "Green",
        quantity: 4
      }
];

console.log(regroupArray(data));
```

Comment: If the `variations` array needs to have the color to be stored as `name`, then a minor change will be needed when populating the array. Instead of using `color, quantity`, one may need to use: `name: color, quantity`.